# How to do admin ajax request in a plugin for rest api

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, actions, rest-api

This must be something very simple, but I cannot figure it out.

I'm working on a plugin, that extends a theme's functionality to rest api. Theme has an ajax action function that updates user profile. Here's the code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_profile', 'update_profile' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_profile', 'update_profile' );

if( !function_exists('update_profile') ):
    function update_profile(){
        //update profile discipline
        ......    
        echo json_encode( array( 'success' => true) );
        die();
    }
endif;
```

Now I want to use this action in my plugin, and do something after it has returned. But since it has `die()` at the end, I cannot continue my execution after action. Here's how I'm calling it in my plugin:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'mobile-api/v1', '/update-profile', array(
      'methods' => 'POST',
      'callback' => 'editProfile',
    ));
});
function editProfile() {
    do_action("wp_ajax_update_profile");

    $response = array(); //<---- this doesn't get executed
    $response["works"] = "Voila!";
    wp_send_json($response, 200);
}
```

I've tried `ob_get_contents()` but it won't go past the die method.

Editing the theme is not an option.

How can I avoid the `die()` from theme action and return my own response?

Or what is the best way to do a an admin ajax request from plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the goal is here? You're trying to replace an admin-ajax.php request with a REST API request, but you're just triggering the AJAX request code anyway, so the only thing you're changing is the request URL. Everything else is the same. I'm not sure what the point of this is?

Comment: @JacobPeattie There's a bug in original action. I want to rectify by undoing a thing, that was done in action.